# no match for call in STL

Tags: c++, stl

i am storing pointer to object in vector(STL). and i am performing some operation based on Account number , i am using lambda function to solve it .
But I am getting some error .
How to fixed it ???

```
class BankingSystem {
  vector <Account *> vobject;
 public :
  BankingSystem();
  void Create_new_Account();
  void Account_info();
  void Get_All_Account_info();
  void Withdraw();
};

void BankingSystem :: Account_info()
{
    long int ACC_NUMBER;
    cout << "Enter AccountNumber : " <<endl;
    cin >> ACC_NUMBER;

    vector<Account*> :: iterator mAccount = std::find_if(vobject.begin(), vobject.end(),
                                 [&ACC_NUMBER](const Account& a) {
                                     // acc_number is maybe called something else in
                                     // your Account class.
                                     return a.Acc_holder.Account_number == ACC_NUMBER;
                                 });
    if(mAccount != vobject.end())
    {                                
        cout << (*mAccount)->Acc_holder.Account_number << endl;
        cout << (*mAccount)->Acc_holder.aadharNo << endl;
        vobject.erase(mAccount); // not "delete mAccount;"
    }
}
```

This is an error . i am not getting what exactly the error is ? please elaborate it .

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                     from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                     from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                     from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                     from /home/pankaj/BANK/./include/stdheader.h:4,
                     from /home/pankaj/BANK/src/bankingSystem.cpp:1:
    /usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<account**, std::vector<account*> >; _Predicate = BankingSystem::Account_info()::<lambda(Account&)>]’:
    /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<account**, std::vector<account*> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<BankingSystem::Account_info()::<lambda(Account&)> >]’
    /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from ‘_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<account**, std::vector<account*> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<BankingSystem::Account_info()::<lambda(Account&)> >]’
    /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:3932:28:   required from ‘_IIter std::find_if(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<account**, std::vector<account*> >; _Predicate = BankingSystem::Account_info()::<lambda(Account&)>]’
    /home/pankaj/BANK/src/bankingSystem.cpp:40:35:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: no match for call to ‘(BankingSystem::Account_info()::<lambda(Account&)>) (account*&)’
      { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /home/pankaj/BANK/src/bankingSystem.cpp:36:58: note: candidate: BankingSystem::Account_info()::<lambda(Account&)>
                                      [&ACC_NUMBER](Account& a) {
                                                              ^
    /home/pankaj/BANK/src/bankingSystem.cpp:36:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘account*’ to ‘Account& {aka account&}’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this line of your code:

```
vector<Account*> :: iterator mAccount = std::find_if(vobject.begin(), vobject.end(),
                             [&ACC_NUMBER](const Account& a) {
```

Your lambda should accept an `Account *`, not an `Account`, because you are iterating over a `std::vector<Account *>`.

Comment: Still i not got a solution                                                                                                        yes i defined the class in this way 
It is same as follows :
class BankingSystem 
{
 vector <Account *> vobject; 
 public :
  BankingSystem();
  void Create_new_Account();
  void Account_info();
  void Get_All_Account_info();
  void Withdraw();
};

Comment: @PANKAJLADE: Does this answer not make sense? The parameters of your lamba should match the contents of the vector, which it doesn't.

Comment: yes it worked for me . I understood  where i was doing mistake . Thank you.